# Bresenham's Line Algorithm versus Naive Vector Addition

Tags: c++, optimization, bresenham

Given `xlen` is delta-x, `ylen` is delta-y, `len` is the length of the line, why is this code:

```
//Bresenham implementation
float x = x0, y = y0;

if (slope < 1) {
    while (x < xlen) {
        paintpt(x, y));
         x += step;
        if (left.y > right.y) 
            y += slope * step;
        else 
            y -= slope * step;
   }
}
```

any more efficient than this code?

```
//Naive vector addition
int x = x0, y = y0;
float xinc = xlen / len, yinc = ylen / len;

for (float i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   paintpt(x, y);
   x += i * xinc;
   y += i * yinc;
}
```

(I mean, aside from initialization, obviously. Assume that you're only given the line-length and direction and have to back out the slope and whatnot, or something.)

Comment: If I remember that right, it's not the same. Bresenham's "steps" vary.

Comment: What are tupes of step and slope? I bet these are integer type variables, while in the naive addition you have multiplication of float values which is much, much more expensive.

Comment: Also, Bresenham will have less iterations, and half as much multiplications and assignments by the cost of one extra comparison operation each step (and I really believe that `if (left.y > right.y)` is faster than `x += i * xinc;`, especially considering that `xinc` is `float`.

Comment: `int step`, but `float slope` - or you couldn't handle anything other than integer or integer-reciprocal slopes.

Comment: Also, pardon me, but why is int arithmetic so much faster? I hear it a lot, but I don't know enough CPU guts to know why.

Comment: Bresenham can draw `--...` (two pixels horizontally, and three horizontally in the next line). Can you second version do the same? If yes, how?

Comment: @link, Well, let's start with the fact that most floating-point numbers can't be accurately represented in binary, and they are stored in an "odd" format, while integers, on the other hand, can. If you are interested in the subject, I would recommend you reading this article: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: IMHO, it's not really Bresenham if it starts with `float x =`

Comment: both pieces of code are screwed up.  here, read about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm

Comment: Real optimized Bresenham uses no floating points and has no multiplications inside loop.

Comment: There isn't any *Bresenham algorithm* at all here.

Comment: Whoops - right, slope * step can be moved outside the loop. Why can you get rid of floating points entirely?

Comment: Wait, read answers, nevermind. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `x += i * xinc;` this is a float multiplication rounded to an integer. It doesn't guarantee you to go through all integers from you starting `x` to your final `x`. This means your line may have holes in it...

2) Your Bresenham implementation is wrong. You do not add steps to `x`. You increment `x`on every iteration and add `delta_y` to an error counter. When the error counter is larger than `delta_x` you increment `y` and substract `delta_x` from the error counter.

This is the explanation for a line whose `delta_y` is greater than 0 and inferior to `delta_x`. Do the rotation for all other cases.

3) For efficiency: this is a bit tricky. Oldest computers could not do floating point computation easily. Up until the Pentium it was common to not have any x87 coprocessor and all floating point computation was done in software. This was 1000s times slower than doing simple integer arithmetic. Nowadays all computers can do SIMD operations (i.e. they use [floating-point vector extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions)); it may not be the case any more.

Comment: SIMD doesn't imply floating point operations, by the way.  Many DSPs that support SIMD still don't do float natively.  For the ones that do  float in hardware, it is still slower than int in hardware.

Comment: You're correct. My answer is heavily simplified and biased towards x86 CPU.

Comment: It's not just heavily simplified.  It's not quite right.  floating point operations are faster in the pentium (than older processors) not because pentium can do SIMD.  It's because the pentium has built in floating point operations.  That the MMX instructions share the register set with the floating point unit is just a design detail.  SIMD and floating point operations are functionally different things.  In fact, if you use SIMD in the pentium, then floating point operations are emulated.  In order to use SIMD, you can't use float operations anymore due to shared registers with float stack.

Comment: Well, it depends what SIMD instruction set is. If you can multiply 4 floats in single cycle, of course that makes multiplication faster (if  it applies to the problem).

Comment: @thang Isn't it what I said ? `Up until the Pentium it was common to not have any x87 coprocessor and all floating point computation was done in software.`. Pentium is 20years old, when I say: *nowadays* SIMD changes the game, I think more about latest AVX than MMX.

Comment: @fjardon, "nowadays SIMD changes the game" is not necessarily true in the context of float operations.  SIMD is *not* the reason why float operations are faster now.  built-in FPU is the reason!  You are confounding these two.  Having SIMD doesn't imply having FPU.  Sometimes it so happens that they exist on the same platform (as in Pentium), but it is not necessarily so.

Comment: @dbrank0, I will reiterate the first thing I said "SIMD doesn't imply floating point operations".

Answer (score 5):

The Bresenham algorithm hails from the 60's, when computers fit into big closets. Its hallmarks were/are:

- no floating point math,
- no multiplications/divisions.

Since in those days, even integer divisions and multiplications were "expensive". A "true" Bresenham implementation will not divide/multiply and will not use floating point math. Your implementation is "false". Check [here](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=Bresenham%27s_Line_Algorithm) for a "true" one.

Comment: What the? There's even a template metaprogramming implementation for it?

Comment: @ChristianRau Yeah, Bresenham's algorithm is very important to the roguelike programming community.